# Let $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ a function given condition. Does $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. Suppose that $C\subseteq (0,1)$ is a countable subset such that for every $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $(0,1) \setminus C$ we have that

$$f(x_n) \to a$$

Can we conclude that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = a$?

I know the answer is true without the $C$, and I can prove this too. I tried to immitate the proof of that case but it didn't quite work out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational. With $C = \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ and $a = 0$, all your assumptions are satisfied, however you have $f(\frac{1}{n}) = 1 \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$ and thus $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need $C$ to be dense and $f$ to be continuous for this to work.  $C$ could be contained in $(0.1,1)$ according to your definition and then provides no information about what happens near zero.  You need continuity as shown in Mattias Klupsch's answer.